# How could i make it so that my code skips a line in a for loop

Tags: c++, clion

Im trying to skip line number 13 but i don't know how to really go about this

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int i, j;
    cout << "Type in the elevator where you want to proceed: "  << endl;
    cin >> j;
    for(i=1;  i<= j; i++) {
    if ( i==13)continue;
    cout << "Your elevator number is at: " << i << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (x == 13) continue;`. The initialization in your loop `x>=1` makes no sense. The result of the check is not used.

Comment: Just about anything you do to skip entering the body of the loop will cost more than entering the loop and only doing something  `if(x != 13)`

Comment: Note: `x>=1` in the for loop doesn't do anything that I can think of.

Comment: A sort-of example you might be able to adapt to your needs: https://ideone.com/sYvR1i

Comment: @user4581301 Soo i made some few corrections and i was wondering if this seems okay now.

Comment: What about your code doesn't work? Your new code works just fine, assuming `j >= 13`